# How do I enable salsa on windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Per the [release notes here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Updates)
I have to set an environmental variable VSCODE_TSJS. But is that referring to the machine, npm, or what?

I've set it in both places but it doesn't seem to be having an effect.

Comment: Your issue is outdated now, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what did you mean by "both places", but the correct place could be either user environment variables or system environment variables. And you'd better set it with some value like "1".

To do so:

1. Press Start button, type "system environment variables", select the matching item and hit enter.
2. Click "Environment Variables..." button at right bottom, and it prompts environment variables window.
3. Then click "New..." button under either user or system scope, and add variable with name "VSCODE_TSJS" and value "1".
4. Click "OK", and "OK".
5. Make sure you have latest TypeScript package installed globally.

Now you may restart your VS Code. If you are launching Code via a command prompt, be sure to restart the command prompt first.

Comment: By both places, I meant I set the environment variable at the machine level, as well as the node environment. However, I set the machine variable through the SET command at the terminal, but for whatever reason, that didn't work. Your method did work, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is [enabled by default](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/vFebruary)  since February 2016 (VSCode v0.10.11).